# Why doesn't my service startup during Bootup?

Tags: android, service, crash

Does anyone know why my service cannot be started when i boot up my Android phone? I am trying to link my service to my activity class, and when the activity crashes, the service will relaunch the activity again. My service class is as follows

```
public class Restarter extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();   
    Log.v("Restarter", "Restarter Created");
}

 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {
     Stamp_Client sc = new Stamp_Client();
        System.out.println("Restarter Service Started");
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Checking for crash...");
        int instance;
        instance = sc.nbInstances();
        if(instance == 0){
            Intent myIntent = 
           new Intent(Restarter.this,Stamp_Client.class);
            Restarter.this.startActivity(myIntent); 
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    }   }
```

My manifest is as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.i2r.cas.mofa.main"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
    </uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS">
 </uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
 </uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
 </uses-permission>

  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Stamp_Client"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"          
               android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">


   <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".Restarter" >
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.i2r.cas.mofa.main.Restarter">
    </action>
 </intent-filter>
  </service>    


  <receiver android:name=".StartAtBootServiceReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
    </action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME">
    </category>
</intent-filter>
    </receiver>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>

   </manifest>
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't get called during bootup? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file you declared the element in the wrong manner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.i2r.cas.mofa.main"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
</uses-permission>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".Stamp_Client"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"          
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".Restarter" >
  <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.i2r.cas.mofa.main.Restarter">
       </action>
    </intent-filter>
 </service>    
 <receiver android:name=".StartAtBootServiceReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
                 </action>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME">
             </category>
       </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

In your `StartBootServiceReceiver` call the startService(intent of the service class) method